# CSS background has invalid property value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I put the below CSS rules in database that are valid in Google Chrome:

```
background: url(/lib/editor/frames/6.1.png) center -7px / 19mm 12mm no-repeat, url(/lib/editor/frames/6.2.png) center 0px / 500mm 1.4mm no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(211, 233, 203) 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%) center 5px / 500mm 3.7mm no-repeat;
background-color: white;
```

When I try to add this rules to a div with JQuery, this rule merged as single rule and get invalid value

```
background: url(/lib/editor/frames/6.1.png) center -7px / 19mm 12mm no-repeat white, url(/lib/editor/frames/6.2.png) center 0px / 500mm 1.4mm no-repeat white, linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(211, 233, 203) 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%) center 5px / 500mm 3.7mm no-repeat;
```

How do I know why it is invalid?

Comment: "How do I know why it is invalid?" You can find out by referring to the spec. Here's where you need to look: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @Soviut I use the jQuery v1.9.1.

Comment: That is a very old version of jquery. See if it happens in a newer version, then report your findings to the jQuery repository. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues

Comment: Thank you @Sovit. Let me update my JQuery and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you've identified this as a bug this is a bug with a recent version of JQuery, you should report it to the [JQuery GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues) issues page; Not here.

A workaround would be to simply set the the style attribute manually.

```
$('.whatever').attr('style', 'background: url(/lib/editor/frames/6.1.png) center -7px / 19mm 12mm no-repeat, url(/lib/editor/frames/6.2.png) center 0px / 500mm 1.4mm no-repeat, linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(211, 233, 203) 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%) center 5px / 500mm 3.7mm no-repeat; background-color: white;');
```

Comment: But it *is* invalid. The background-color value may only appear once at most and it must be in the last layer (which implies that the background-color of every other layer is always transparent without having to specify it). Whatever jQuery is doing is a bug and should be treated as such.

Comment: @Soviut your solution has a problem. please see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/9qgpbryy/

Comment: @NaserYousefi I've updated my answer since this probably is a bug. Report it to the JQuery repository on github, not here.

Comment: @Soviut I have to add a bunch of CSS rules using cssText. I tried to add this rules one by one but it's not worked too.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
background-image:url('url')
```